# Album sharing with Google Photos API

Tags: api, web-applications, photo

I am using Google Photo API in my webapp and have successfully created an album and media items. I would like to share these Albums with my users (internal GApps domain users) so they see the shared albums via the google photos app.

I have used this link (https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/share-media#joining-shared-album) but how does this work without knowing user's oauth 2 token. I need to share my albums with multi users using code to be seen in Google Photos App but I don't want to use mail function. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: any help on this would be greatly appreciated thanks